# How can I unwrap a mesh like this

Tags: uv

I have this mesh which is supposed to be edge of the roof of the building, I have marked seams like shown in the picture but the textures are appearing streched I don't know why I have applied scale and rotation, I have also tried cube projection, cylinder projection and smart uv unwrap but nothing seems to work

[image: v]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's very hard to understand what your mesh looks like, plus you don't show the UV map, could you please show more or even share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, I have added the blend file now

Comment: it looks like if you apply the mirror and use Conformal instead of Angle Based mode (once you've unwrapped, in the Operator box), it works fine. Angle Based seems better for organic objects, Conformal for angular ones.

Comment: Sorry nothing is happening in my project when I do that

Comment: weird, perhaps try Unwrap > Reset, then Unwrap again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Moonboots has already suggested use the **Conformal** method when unwrapping.

Then In the **Object Data Properties** panel > **UV Maps** select the **Leak** UV map and click on the little camera icon to make it the active UV map.

[image]